# how to run mahout kmeans algorithm in local mode

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, mahout

Is it possible to run a mahout k mean java program on local, so that it will read the data from local and save it back to local file system instead of hdfs.
All examles on internet are working on hdfs.

https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/blob/master/src/main/java/mia/clustering/ch07/SimpleKMeansClustering.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible - checkout SequenceFileWriter. See the following code example, which writes clustered data points to a file. Here is a [blog](http://skife.org/mahout/2013/02/14/first_steps_with_mahout.html) post that describes this in great detail:

```
public static void writePointsToFile(List<Vector> points,
                                     String fileName,
                                     FileSystem fs,
                                     Configuration conf) throws IOException {
    Path path = new Path(fileName);
    SequenceFile.Writer writer = new SequenceFile.Writer(fs, conf,
            path, LongWritable.class, VectorWritable.class);
    long recNum = 0;
    VectorWritable vec = new VectorWritable();
    for (Vector point : points) {
        vec.set(point);
        writer.append(new LongWritable(recNum++), vec);
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: You are using path class .. Isn't this going to write on hdfs?

Comment: Path is based on org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path. And, whether it is written to a local filesystem or not, is based on FileSystem per  org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem. If you initialize with local configuration, files will be written to local file system. The concrete class RawLocalFileSystem will enable local filesystem, or a default configuration as in: Filesystem fs = new FileSystem.get(new Configuration()) would get it to use the local filesystem.